# Scrolling a listbox inside a stackpanel?

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

So here is what my wp8.1 app is about: I have a stackpanel, containing (from top to bottom) a horizontal listbox, a pivot and listboxes in the pivotitems. I am attempting to scroll down the listbox contained in the pivot. I have managed to do this by setting a fixed height to the listbox, but the display needs to be scalable to any screen height, and so the listbox height needs to be set on Automatic. but that makes it unscrollable :/ Is there any way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot scroll the listbox with automatic height. You can use grid with rowdefinition instead of stackpanel to contains the listbox. The example is like this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="100" /><!--this is for any item above your listbox-->
     <RowDefinition Height="*" /><!--This is for your listbox so it can occupy the space left from the grid-->
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Pivot Grid.Row="0" />
   <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource={Binding Something} />
</Grid>
```